# Passing JSession ID to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jakarta-ee

For troubleshooting purpose, I am trying to pass the JsessionID from a web application running on Tomcat to the back-end Oracle DB. The idea is to link each SQL query executed from the web application with the corresponding JSessionID, so that we can look in the log files specific to that session and try to replicate the session, in case of any long running queries. Since there are a lot of SQL queries being executed from the web application, I am looking for a solution that do not require any modifications to the existing SQL queries.

Is it possible to pass the JSessionID as some sort of metadata to the SQL connection being used to execute the query.

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: You mean by magic?

Comment: I am not sure at all if its possible to pass metadata for each connection that we use to execute a query. That's why I would like to know if anyone has attempted something like this in the past.